# One-element model of first-order PA

Tags: number-theory, model-theory, natural-numbers, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

The First-Order axiomatisation of PA is:

1. $\forall x. x = x$
2. $\forall x, y. x = y \rightarrow y = x$
3. $\forall x, y, z. x = y \land y = z \rightarrow x = z$
4. $\forall x. 0 \ne S(x)$
5. $\forall x, y. S(x) = S(y) \rightarrow x = y$
6. $\forall x. x + 0 = x$
7. $\forall x, y. x + S(y) = S(x + y)$
8. $\forall x. x * 0 = 0$
9. $\forall x, y. x * S(y) = x*y + x$
10. Axiom schema

Now a thing is eating at me. Why is it that a model where $0$ is the only natural number and $S(x)$ is defined nowhere isn't a model of PA? If $S(0)$ doesn't exist, and furthermore $S(x)$ doesn't exist for any x, wouldn't that be also a nonstandard model?

Comment: Too simplistic for an answer, but: You're not allowed to not define $S(x)$ for any members $x$ of your model; $S$ is assumed to be a _total_ (not partial) function.  This is generally made explicit in other axiomatizations.

Comment: Yeah, in other axiomatisations it is, but I see this one used all over (my Model Theory book, for instance, or the W), and totality of S(x) isn't defined anywhere in the axioms, which is why I ask. And there's also the more interesting question of what would happen if I *didn't* assume S(x) to be total.

Comment: The totality of S is part of the underlying first-order logic (the definition of terms, formulas, etc in the language). If S were allowed to be a partial function, then these wouldn't "be" the axioms of PA.

Comment: Pedro: for one you'd have to substantially revise all of the axioms involving successor (e.g., informally: "if S(y) and S(x+y) exist then x+S(y) = S(x+y)"); if you do that, then I believe any finite subset $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ with S defined everywhere that it 'should' be (i.e., on all $x\in A$ with $x+1\in A$) would satisfy your axioms.

Comment: If it's the case that S(x) is defined nowhere (or defined only for finitely many x), then axioms 5, 7 and 9 are vacuously true when S(x), S(y) and S(x + y) isn't defined, no?

Comment: The theory you get after removing axiom 4 does have a one element model. It would be the unique model where S(0)=0.

Comment: @RussellEasterly Removing axiom 4 gives you model for every finite cardinality. The Lowenheim-Skolem theorem guarantees it, but it's easy to construct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particular feature of axiomatizations in first-order logic. First-order logic proves
$$
(\forall x)(\exists y)[S(x) = y]
$$
as part of a general pattern of proving
$$
(\forall x)(\exists y)[t(x) = y]
$$
whenever $t$ is a term whose only free variable is $x$. To avoid this you would have to work in what is known as "free logic".

But there is little interest in that for the specific case of PA, because of course we *do* want the successor function to be total, so the fact that the logic ensures this is convenient.

Comment: As I commented above, isn't that... kind of limited? As in, do all functions then have to be total?

Comment: @Pedro Carvalho: the interpretation of any function *symbol* has to be total. There are plenty of ways to handle non-total functions in the usual first-order setting - the most direct way is to use a relation symbol $R$ instead of a function symbol, with the axiom that $(\forall x)(\exists^{\leq 1} y) R(x,y)$. Then instead of $f(x) = y$ we write $R(x,y)$. But for the specific purpose of PA we want $S$ to be total anyway, so we may as well just use a function symbol and be done with it.

Comment: ...huh. Okay. Sounds roundabout, but okay.

Answer (score 2):

In first-order logic, we require that a function symbol is interpreted as a function whose domain is the entire universe of the structure (or the appropriate tuples, if we consider functions of more than one variable).

This means that $S(0)$ has to be defined. In particular, $S(0)\neq 0$ because $\forall x(S(x)\neq 0)$.

Comment: ...huh. I did not know that. Or maybe I knew it and then promptly forgot. So first-order logic doesn't allow partial functions in its models? That sounds... unnecessarily limited.

Comment: Why? When we say $f\colon A\to B$ we require that the domain of $f$ is $A$, not a subset of $A$.

Comment: Sure, and nowhere in the axioms is it said that $S: N\rightarrow N$. It's just *assumed* as a part of the first-order logic that's in the background, apparently.

Comment: Pedro, there are ways of dealing with that (e.g. adding a new element to which all the elements not in the domain are mapped). Or restricting yourself to a substructure when needed. Or defining a function mapping $x$ to $0$ if it doesn't have a square root, then you can always verify whether or not the returned value is actually the square root or not, thus completing the problem. Moreover in computability we usually care about partial functions, but those are not functions in the language, but rather definable functions. If you want to add them to the language, you need to extend their domain

Comment: [...] and perhaps add a predicate as to what the domain is. Luckily, this can be solved even easier in the case of $\Bbb N$. You can just add a predicate which encodes the ordered pairs of the partial function, and don't care about partial functions in the language or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not used to working in *first-order* PA, but if you had $N=\{ 0 \}$ and assumed $S: N\to N$ (as suggested in comments)  you would have to have $S(0)=0$, contradicting (4).

Comment: Yes, exactly, which is why if S was defined nowhere (or defined only for finitely many numbers) you could have a finite model of those axioms.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho Not sure about the first-order theory, but otherwise, you would have to modify your axioms, but only slightly. On this topic, you might have a look at my blog entry, "Arithmetic on Finite Sets" (April 23, 2014) at http://www.dcproof.wordpress.com You can construct addition and maybe multiplication on any finite set, but I don't know if you can do much more, e.g. establishing associativity, commutativity, etc